# Синтаксическая ошибка в названии файла

Tags: java

При работе с сериализацией столкнулся с такой проблемой, что если в названии создаваемого файла окажется знак `?` то вылетает ошибка:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\bin\saves\4. Test?.ser
> (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома)

При чем абсолютно не важно в какой части названия знак вопроса:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\bin\saves\4. Te?st.ser
> (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома)

Сама строка создания потока сериализации выглядит так:

```
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("./bin/saves/" + but.getText() + ".ser"));
```

Где я через `but.getText()` передаю будущее название файла. С остальными знаками я подобной проблемы вроде не испытываю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Windows` это не `UNIX` !

Здесь спецсимволы, в т. ч. знак вопроса `?`, в названиях файлов использовать нельзя.